# Python Seaborn: Grouped box plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import os
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
df = pd.read_csv("C:/tmp/all.csv")  
sns.boxplot(x="cluster", y="val",
            hue="type", palette=["m", "g"],
            data=df)
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
```

My CSV is:

```
index, cluster, type, val
1, 0-10, male, 1
2, 30-40, female, 5
3, 30-40, male, 3
4, 50-60, male, 7
5, 50-60, female, 1
...
```

The max value of val is 10.

My output is:

[image]

But what I want is: o boxplot of values in a grouped way. In my output I'm getting the number of counts for each cluster. The maximum val is actually 10. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed the values after pd.read? Try running a df.describe(include=“all”)

Comment: Can you add the output of `df.tail()` to verify that the dataframe really is as described?

Comment: I checked again and can really confirm, that the dataframe is as described above.

Comment: @Kosmos here is the output I get for describe https://i.ibb.co/KDkR02K/grafik.png

Comment: @CenkTen According to this information, there is at least one value above 2000. See max of val. what you can do is limit the scope of y using plt.ylim([-1,11]), but this would only hide the outliers outside of the drawing area

Comment: how do you know that there are outliers?

Comment: The boxplot marks anything outside the whiskers as outliers. See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are significant outliers beyond your described upper limit of 10. This can be seen visually in the figure, as well as in the table submitted in comments.

**limit y scope - quick and dirty approach #1**
Set the limit y manually like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ylim([-1,11])
```

In your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # <--- import here
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import os
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
df = pd.read_csv("C:/tmp/all.csv")  
sns.boxplot(x="cluster", y="val",
            hue="type", palette=["m", "g"],
            data=df)
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
plt.ylim([-1,11]) # <--- limit y here
```

**Not showing outliers - quick and dirty approach #2**
Change setting of `sns.boxplot()`

```
sns.boxplot(showfliers = False)
```

Both approaches would concentrate the graph on the inter quartile information. I would prefer approach #1 since it does not remove the outliers, but #2 does not need manual configuration.

Comment: sns.boxplot(showfliers = False)  works but without outliers. How about plt? I don't have a plt object?

Comment: Sorry but I still dont understand how should I put your first solution in my case